# Windows 10 mobile (UWP) Flyout with calendar picker locking on screen

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I've created flyout to my appbarbutton with one textbox an control to pick a date 'CalendarDatePicker'.

The problem is that when I choose a date from control calendar is shown and my flyout dissapear. I thought about locking my Flyout, but I don't know how do to it. It dissapear even when I click outside of flyout. Is it possible?

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="btnAppAddEvent" Icon="Add" Label="Dodaj"  >
            <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                <Flyout x:Name="flAdd" Placement="Full" >
                    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="350"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="300"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF8096BD"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>

                    <StackPanel Height="300"  >
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtNameAdd"  FontSize="23"  Height="40"></TextBox>

                        <CalendarDatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Center"  x:Name="calendar" Margin="0,30,0,0" />
                        <AppBarButton x:Name="btnAddEv" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Icon="Accept" Click="btnAddEv_Click"  Margin="0,20,0,0"></AppBarButton>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtMess2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="15" Foreground="Red" Margin="0,10,0,0"  ></TextBlock>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Flyout>
            </AppBarButton.Flyout>
        </AppBarButton>
```

Comment: I was experiencing the same behaviour with the same sample. I don't think it is possible to do it with a Flyout . I think I used ContentDialog. You can also try Popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that when I choose a date from control calendar is shown and my flyout dissapear.

I tested your code on my side. In the newest windows 10 SDK build 14393 this issue is no longer existed. When we choose a data from calendar control which is inside the `Flyout` control, the `Flyout` will not disappear. But in previous SDK like build 10586 your issue is existed and it seems like currently we cannot change it by setting.

> It dissapear even when I click outside of flyout.

For this scenario it is by design. According to the description of [`Flyout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx) control:

> Represents a control that displays lightweight UI that is either information, or requires user interaction. Unlike a dialog, a Flyout can be light dismissed by clicking or tapping outside of it, pressing the device’s back button, or pressing the ‘Esc’ key.

`Flyout` control is designed for displaying lightweight UI and can be light dismissed. If you don't want the UI dismissed by tapping outside you can try other fly out controls like [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) control. For more details about ContentDialog please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics/cs/AppUIBasics/ControlPages/ContentDialogExample.xaml).